# wikipedia page, how to display current date in yyyymmdd?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to display current date in yyyymmdd format in our company's internal wiki page. I have looked through mediawiki page for guidance, but it seems like that I need to link to some libraries or template. In general, it's a little difficult to navigate on mediawiki's page and learn necessary "programming language". Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{CURRENTYEAR}}{{CURRENTMONTH}}{{CURRENTDAY2}}
```

Due to MediaWiki and browser caching, these variables frequently show when the page was cached rather than the current time.

Source: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words

Comment: you are absolutely correct! But could you please edit your post such that there are two {{ before CURRENTDAY2? I can't edit it if i made change less than 6 characters